# LWC: lightning-input checkbox disabled css

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I am writing an LWC component where as per design received, need to customize lightning-input checkbox.

Customized output:

[image]

Code Used: I have used styling hooks as per documentation from salesforce to achieve above UI styling

```
:host {
    --sds-c-checkbox-color-background-checked: #0769fd;
    --sds-c-checkbox-mark-color-foreground: #fff;
}
```

I am disabling the checkbox based on some business scenarios with standard disable attribute of html element/lightning-input element as below. You can see it's a standard CSS behavior when disabled attribute is enabled for an html element.

[image]

**ISSUE:**

Instead of above disabled design I would like to achieve below UI.

[image]

So basically same background with opacity may be .4 or .5. The issue is I am not getting selector to do this. Any idea. I have gone through the documentation of styling hooks but none seems to be working

```
:host .slds-checkbox_faux {
     opacity: 0.4 !important;
     background: lightblue !important;
     border: 10px solid red !important;
 }

 :host input[disabled]{ /* css properties */}
 :host input[type='checkbox'][disabled][checked]:after{ /* css properties */}
 :host input[type='checkbox'][disabled][checked]{ /* css properties */}
```

and what not but none seems to be attaching when I debug the input element.

Let me know if you guys can help or need more info.

Thanks,
UI Developer :)

Comment: due to the shadow DOM, I think you can not access/modify the styling properties (besides the ones listed on the Styling Hooks) so you might need to use the standard `<input type="checkbox">` tag

Comment: That is what my conclusion is.